# compare two dates in html angularjs ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

So basically i have this html file that displays a list of notification messages and i want to be able to know the difference between the time for each notification but not sure how to do it in html

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="single in notifications_list track by $index" class="ng-scope" ng-class="single.read == true ? 'notification-read' : 'notification-unread'" ng-click="displayNotification(single)" style="padding:13px 16px 1px;">
        <div class="notifications">
            <p style="white-space:normal;font-size:16px;line-height:20px;">{{single.body}}</p>
            {{(currentDate - single.time).getDays()}}
            <time>{{ single.time | amCalendar:referenceTime:formats }}</time>
        </div>
    </ion-item>
```

i have already created somewhere in my code that `$rootScope.currentDate = new Date();`

so `e.g. 2016-05-11T10:30:48.616Z - 2016-05-10T19:14:13.487+08:00` this is basically what i want to do in html view and return the difference in days.

How can i do that? Pls advise

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you, time ago angularjs plugin allow to show the time in human readable firmat....for example like few time ago,,,,,hours ago,,,,etc

[Link](https://github.com/uttesh/ngtimeago)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using amCalendar, so I'm guessing you are already using the angular-moment plugin.

If so, you could use the [amDifference filter](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#amdifference-filter)

So I guess you could do something like:

```
<time>{{ single.time | amDifference : null : 'days' }}</time>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [use moment.js so Calculation on Dates and Times](http://momentjs.com/)

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="single in notifications_list track by $index" class="ng-scope" ng-class="single.read == true ? 'notification-read' : 'notification-unread'" ng-click="displayNotification(single)" style="padding:13px 16px 1px;">
    <div class="notifications">
        <p style="white-space:normal;font-size:16px;line-height:20px;">{{single.body}}</p>
        {{getDiff(single.time)}}
        <time>{{ single.time | amCalendar:referenceTime:formats }}</time>
    </div>
</ion-item>
```

in controller:

```
$scope.getDiff=function(time){
var now=moment();
return  now.diff(time, 'days') 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [angular-duration-format](https://github.com/erykpiast/angular-duration-format) for this purpose.

Add angular-duration-format as your app dependency.

```
angular.module('myModule', [
'angular-duration-format'
]);
```

In templates you can use

```
<p>
Time passed: {{ passed | duration:'hh:mm:ss:sss' }}<br/>
Preformatted: {{ passedPre }}
</p>
```

In controllers (or directives, services, anywhere)

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('exampleCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
var durationFilter = $filter('duration');

$scope.passed = 123456789;
$scope.passedPre = durationFilter($scope.passed, 'hh:mm:ss:sss');
```

});

The result should be the same in both cases:

```
Time passed: 34:17:36:789
Preformatted: 34:17:36:789
```